# Split string over list of words

Tags: r, regex, string, split

I have a data frame from a second-hand source that has a lot of the key information in one column separated by spaces. I can't simply use `str_split` since some of the key information has a space in the name, but they are preceded by a grouping variable. Here is an example using foods and food-groups:

```
foo1 <- paste('FRUIT', 'Apple', 'PROTEIN', 'Chicken', 'STARCH', 'Banana Bread', 'FRUIT', 'Strawberry')
foo2 <- paste('PROTEIN', 'Pork', 'FAT', 'Butter', 'FRUIT', 'Banana', 'STARCH', 'Spaghetti')
foo3 <- paste('FRUIT', 'Strawberry', 'PROTEIN', 'Lean Steak', 'FRUIT', 'Strawberry', 'STARCH', 'Potato')

df <- rbind(foo1, foo2, foo3)
df

foo1 "FRUIT Apple PROTEIN Chicken STARCH Banana Bread FRUIT Strawberry"  
foo2 "PROTEIN Pork FAT Butter FRUIT Banana STARCH Spaghetti"             
foo3 "FRUIT Strawberry PROTEIN Lean Steak FRUIT Strawberry Starch Potato"
```

In this scenario, the key pieces I'd want to grab are the actual food, but I can't split over spaces since things like "Banana Bread" exist. Therefore, I could split only over FRUIT, PROTEIN, STARCH, or FAT, but I can't figure out a good way to do this. In my actual table, there are still only 4 "groupings", but over 500 individual items, so it would be a huge pain to try to map the specific ones with spaces. The following lines don't work:

```
str_split(df, c('FRUIT', 'PROTEIN', 'STARCH', 'FAT'))
str_split_fixed(df, c('FRUIT', 'PROTEIN', 'STARCH', 'FAT'), 4)
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regex to do that :

```
str_split(df, c('FRUIT|PROTEIN|STARCH|FAT'))
[[1]]
[1] ""               " Apple "        " Chicken "      " Banana Bread " " Strawberry"   

[[2]]
[1] ""           " Pork "     " Butter "   " Banana "   " Spaghetti"

[[3]]
[1] ""             " Strawberry " " Lean Steak " " Strawberry " " Potato"
```

Use the collapse arg in paste to turn your vec into regex :

```
paste(c('FRUIT', 'PROTEIN', 'STARCH', 'FAT'), collapse = '|')
[1] "FRUIT|PROTEIN|STARCH|FAT"
```

Best,

Colin

Answer (score 3):

Since you only want the foods, the followin approach using `tidyverse` should do the trick:

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

foo1 <- paste('FRUIT', 'Apple', 'PROTEIN', 'Chicken', 'STARCH', 'Banana Bread', 'FRUIT', 'Strawberry')
foo2 <- paste('PROTEIN', 'Pork', 'FAT', 'Butter', 'FRUIT', 'Banana', 'STARCH', 'Spaghetti')
foo3 <- paste('FRUIT', 'Strawberry', 'PROTEIN', 'Lean Steak', 'FRUIT', 'Strawberry', 'STARCH', 'Potato')

df <- rbind(foo1, foo2, foo3) %>%
  as_tibble()
```

(note the use of `as_tibble()` to convert your data frame to a tibble object - easier to work with)

Now for the actual stuff:

```
df.new <- df %>% 
   mutate(clean.str = str_replace_all(V1, pattern = "(FRUIT|PROTEIN|STARCH|FAT)", replacement = "|") %>%
       str_sub(start = 3)) %>%
   mutate(str.ls = str_split(clean.str, fixed(" | "))) %>%
   unnest() %>% 
   select(str.ls)
```

And here is the result you wanted, a list of the actual food:

```
df.new

# A tibble: 12 x 1
     str.ls
      <chr>
  1        Apple
  2      Chicken
  3 Banana Bread
  4   Strawberry
  5         Pork
  6       Butter
  7       Banana
  8    Spaghetti
  9   Strawberry
 10   Lean Steak
 11   Strawberry
 12       Potato
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this. This looks pretty short and simple to follow.

```
df%>%
strsplit(split = paste(c('FRUIT', 'PROTEIN', 'STARCH', 'FAT'), collapse = "|"))%>%
unlist()%>%
.[. != ""]

 [1] " Apple "        " Chicken "      " Banana Bread " " Strawberry"    " Pork "         " Butter "       " Banana "       " Spaghetti"    
 [9] " Strawberry "   " Lean Steak "   " Strawberry "   " Potato"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `stri_split_regex()` in `unnest_tokens()`, we can deliver the following result. `unnest_tokens()` is a function in the `tidytext` package. Here, I used `stri_split_regex()` as a custom function in `unnest_tokens()`. The regular expression says, "patterns that start with either beginning of a line or white space and repetitive upper letters (one or more times) follow, and the pattern ends with white space". This allows us to split the strings as you described in your question. row names help us see which words are in which strings.

```
library(tidytext)
library(stringi)

df <- data.frame(text = c(foo1, foo2, foo3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>%
unnest_tokens(input = text, output = word, to_lower = FALSE,
              token = stri_split_regex, 
              pattern = "(\\s|^)[A-Z]+\\s", omit_empty = TRUE)

            word
1          Apple
1.1      Chicken
1.2 Banana Bread
1.3   Strawberry
2           Pork
2.1       Butter
2.2       Banana
2.3    Spaghetti
3     Strawberry
3.1   Lean Steak
3.2   Strawberry
3.3       Potato
```

Answer (score 2):

With Base R using `do.call` and `strsplit` you can split and combine the results, with your current setup, you may try:

```
do.call("rbind", strsplit(df[,1], "FRUIT|PROTEIN|STARCH|FRUIT|FAT", perl=T))[,2:5]
```

**Output**:

```
  #         [,1]           [,2]           [,3]             [,4]         
  #  foo1 " Apple "      " Chicken "    " Banana Bread " " Strawberry"
  #  foo2 " Pork "       " Butter "     " Banana "       " Spaghetti" 
  #  foo3 " Strawberry " " Lean Steak " " Strawberry "   " Potato"
```

Answer (score 2):

First note that `df` in the question is a matrix, not a data frame:

```
class(df)
## [1] "matrix"
```

We can use `strsplit` splitting on upper case words and surrounding space using the regular expression `pat`.  Note that `"\\b"` matches a word boundary.  `Filter(nzchar, ...)` removes zero length strings and `unique` removes duplicates.  No packages are used.

```
pat <- " *\\b([A-Z]+)\\b *" 
unique(Filter(nzchar, unlist(strsplit(df[, 1], pat))))
```

giving:

```
[1] "Apple"        "Chicken"      "Banana Bread" "Strawberry"   "Pork"        
[6] "Butter"       "Banana"       "Spaghetti"    "Lean Steak"   "Potato"
```

It could alternately be written using a magrittr pipeline like this:

```
library(magrittr)

df[, 1] %>%
        strsplit(pat) %>%
        unlist %>%
        Filter(nzchar, .) %>%
        unique
```